# Check if cell contains sub string in list - Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a list called `ImageExtensionList` that consists of image extensions.

[image]

Here's my custom data validation.

[image]

Now logically thinking, the value on `J2` will search if it does exist in `ImageExtensionList`

Now when I tried to test the data, it does work on only the first value of the list. But when I tried `jpg` or `jpeg` it prompts an error that it does not exist.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me why it does not work? I found a lot of reference, posts, articles in SO or in some websites. Tried a lot of them but for some reason it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SEARCH` function is used to search for some text inside another text. Not what you need here. Also, you can't just search for the whole file name, you need to extract the extension first.

Here's the validation formula you need:

`=COUNTIF(ImageExtensions, RIGHT(J2,LEN(J2)-FIND(".",J2)))>0`

How it works:

1. `FIND(".",J2)`  finds the position of the period character, where the file extension starts.
2. `LEN(J2)-FIND(".",J2))` gives us the length of the file extension.
3. `RIGHT(J2,LEN(J2)-FIND(".",J2))` takes x characters from the right side of the filename, where x is the length of the extension, thus giving us the file extension.
4. `COUNTIF(ImageExtensions, RIGHT(J2,LEN(J2)-FIND(".",J2)))` is then used to count how many occurrences of the file extension exist in the ImageExtensions list. Any value above 0 is good.